# UI not updated on ObservableCollection change

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, treeview, observablecollection

I want to accomplish the following task:

Display a `TreeView` of resources (e.g. cars, rooms, etc.) with `CheckBoxes` to select items or all of them.

To do that I have a `Dictionary<ResourceCategory, List<Resource>>` that's used as the `TreeView's` `ItemsSource`
and a `MultiBinding` for the `CheckBoxes`inside the `DataTemplate` of which one binds to the resource's Id and the other one to the selected resources `ObservableCollection< Resource>`.

```
<TreeView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Category2ResourcesDictionary}" >
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Value}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Key}" />
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Content="{Binding}" PreviewMouseDown="RessourcenTV_OnClick">
                                <CheckBox.IsChecked>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CheckBoxConverter}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True">
                                        <Binding Path="ResourceId" Mode="OneWay" />
                                        <Binding Path="SelectedResources" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}" />
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </CheckBox.IsChecked>
                            </CheckBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
```

My problem is that, when I add a resource object to the selected resources collection in code behind, its `CheckBox` is still unchecked(the `Convert` method is not called), 
but the selected resources collection contains it.

Why is the `CheckBox` still unchecked?

EDIT:
The `Add()` and `Remove()` methods don't work, but when I assign a new `ObservableCollection` containing the old selected resources collection plus/minus the one I want to add/remove it works just fine. But then I can also use a normal `List`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your problems is that the `Dictionary` which you are using as the `ItemsSource` *doesn't* implement the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface. Another might be that you don't have a specific data type class that implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface that contains *all* of the required properties.

To fix this problem, first define a proper view model class for your data item that implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, including *all* of the required properties that it will need. Then, create an `ObservableCollection` of those objects and bind *that* to the `ListBox.ItemsSource` property instead. Then, when you add an item to the inner collection or make any property changes, you'll see the UI update as expected.